# Famous Framework on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide, famous-cli, famous-framework

Anyone attempted to get a [Famous Framework](http://famous.org/framework/) working on [Cloud9's IDE](https://c9.io/)?

It looks like famous is trying to run on two ports: `1618` for the application itself, and `35729` for livereload. Is this possible on cloud9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud9 IDE only allows you to publicly broadcast on port 8080, so you need to make sure that the application port is set to 8080. Using two separate ports will not work at the moment, but other than the livereload not working, it won't cause any problems with the actual running of the server (you'll just have to keep refreshing manually).